# Xamarin Android 12 - Initial Crash

Tags: xamarin.android, crash-reports

I just worked on my Xamarin Forms App and released the next version for iOS.
Then I went back to the Android version, assuming it would work perfectly well (as android has always been doing for me).

Now this is what happens:

```
[QXPerf] Couldn't load BLASTBufferQueue Class
[QXPerf] Couldn't find UndequeuedBufferCount functions
[Looper] PerfMonitor longMsg : seq=4 plan=10:19:09.074 late=5792ms wall=2177ms running=0ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159 procState=-1
[Looper] PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=de.myapp.app/crc643873299c977c4ba1.MainActivity time=2177ms latency=5792ms running=0ms  procState=-1  historyMsgCount=1 (msgIndex=1 wall=5790ms seq=3 late=1ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110)
[Looper] PerfMonitor looperActivity : package=de.myapp.app/crc643873299c977c4ba1.MainActivity time=0ms latency=7970ms running=0ms  procState=-1  historyMsgCount=2 (msgIndex=1 wall=5790ms seq=3 late=1ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110) (msgIndex=2 wall=2177ms seq=4 late=5792ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=159)
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

[MIUIScout App] Enter APP_SCOUT_WARNING State
[MIUIScout App] Event:APP_SCOUT_WARNING Thread:main backtrace:
[MIUIScout App]     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
[MIUIScout App]     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8085)
[MIUIScout App]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MIUIScout App]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
[MIUIScout App]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
[MIUIScout App] Enter APP_SCOUT_HANG state
[MIUIScout App] Event:APP_SCOUT_HANG Thread:main backtrace:
[MIUIScout App]     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
[MIUIScout App]     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
[MIUIScout App]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8085)
[MIUIScout App]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[MIUIScout App]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
[MIUIScout App]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

I have absolutely no Idea where this comes from or how I could get around it.

Anybody out there, who knows what to do?

Greetings Maurice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Try catch` does not solve the problem , it just stop the crash .

It seems a problem with `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences` in Android 12 , see the issue here : https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/1991 .

For that you can seek another way to replace `Preferences` , or implement [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been caused by a cast using `Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences.Get("Key", false);`

surrounding it with `try{ }catch(Exception e)` lets the App start as requestet.

Comment: Also I discovered scrollview being totally messed up on Android 12. It wont scroll at all (only for listviews) but instead it has the (completely buggy) ability to zoom the entire page content and even turn it up side down…